# Defining cross-reference names for custom theorem environments in cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, amsthm, cleveref

I am concerned with the difference between this working example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}


\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{thm1}
My first theorem
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}\label{thm2}
My second theorem
\end{thm}

Using \cref{thm1,thm2} we obtain another theorem.
\end{document}
```

whose last line is displayed as

> Using ?? 1?? 2 we obtain another theorem.

and the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm1}
My first theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm2}
My second theorem
\end{theorem}

Using \cref{thm1,thm2} we obtain another theorem.
\end{document}
```

whose last displayed line is the intended

> Using Theorems 1 and 2 we obtain another theorem.

I found inside `cleveref.sty` the right (non abbreviated) names of the basic `\newtheorem` definitions (theorem,lemma, corollary, proposition, definition) which are predefined in `cleveref`. But what is the full description that one must give to `cleveref` so that it handles a theorem environment properly (including the `capitalise` option)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `\crefname{<type>}{<singular>}{<plural>}` syntax to define cross reference names for customized theorem-like environments. (see page 12 of the [`cleveref` manual](http://www.dr-qubit.org/latex/cleveref.pdf))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{thm1}
My first theorem
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}\label{thm2}
My second theorem
\end{thm}

Using \cref{thm1,thm2} we obtain another theorem.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. However as far as i understand, this is not in the spirit of cleveref. \crefname should be the lowercase version, while \Crefname is the "beginning of a sentence" form. How do I give the full description to cleveref so that i get the same result as in my second example (also with respect to the capitalise option)?

Comment: Let me be try to make it clearer. In your example code, if you now get rid of the capitalise option, you get exactly the same result. How do I work around this?

Comment: @yann.pequignot: `cleveref` doesn't have a reliable way to determine the plural form of the name for a non-standard theorem-like environment defined by `\newtheorem` (see 7.1.3 of the manual). Therefore, a `\crefname` has to be defined to tell `cleveref` what plural form of the cross reference name it should use. (Note: if only the singular form is used, there's no need to use `\crefname`.)

Comment: @yann.pequignot: However, there seems to be an incompatibility between cross-reference names defined using `\crefname` and the `capitalise` option. The latter option just doesn't "capitalise" the names defined in `\crefname`. To circumvent this issue, I simply used capitalized version even in `\crefname`, which is supposed to be a lowercase version (since you use the `capitalise` option anyway). However, if you'd like to sometimes use lowercase and sometimes uppercase, then just define `\crefname{thm}{theorem}{theorems}`; and use `\cref` for lowercase and `\Cref` for uppercase.

Comment: Thanks. Of course I wanted to let this possibility open, sticking to the spirit of the package. If no better option is available, I'll just define uppercase \crefname and if I change my mind, I'll change these definitions. Still, it is not really satisfactory!

Comment: Of course there's no "conflict" between `\crefname` and the `capitalise` option. To quote the manual: "if you explicitly define a `\cref` variant to *not* be capitalised, `cleveref` will still honour your definition. In other words, you're responsible for defining the capitalisation correctly in your own format definitions." If you want capitalised names in your own format definitions, define `\crefname` to be capitalised.

Comment: It's a common misconception that `\Crefname` means the "capitalised variant" of `\crefname`. It doesn't. `\Crefname` is the *start-of-sentence* variant of `\crefname`. E.g. it doesn't abbreviate names (since you standard style dictates that you shouldn't use abbreviations at the beginning of sentences in English).

Comment: @TobyCubitt: Thanks for the comment, and for writing such a great package `:)` It's been a while since I attempted to answer this question, but I do remember not being able to fully solve the OP's problem. Since you're the author of the `cleveref` package, would you enlighten us on how to solve the OP's problem? In particular, I would really want to know how to **avoid** "explicitly define a `\cref` variant to not be capitalised".

Comment: @KevinC Your solution is perfectly fine. If you want capitalised cross-reference names, define `\crefname` to use capitalised words. If you want non-capitalised names, define `\crefname` to use lower-case words. Yes, this does indeed mean that you'll need to change your `\crefname` definitions if you change your mind about using the `capitalise` package option.

Comment: You really *don't* want `cleveref` to try to (un)capitalise your own `\crefname` definitions for you automatically. Apart from the risk of this going wrong (your `\crefname` could involve arbitrarily complex LaTeX code), you might well *want* lower-case names in some cases. `Cleveref` is clever, but it's not telepathic! It can't tell when you want the capitalisation to respect the package option, and when you're intentionally overriding it. If you *really* need your `\crefname` definitions to respect `capitalise`, use `\if@cref@capitalised` in the definition `\crefname` definition.